# Why cookies are not created with some UTC expiration dates on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, date, cookies, utc

I am trying to set cookies with an expiration date that is 5 minutes later that now. It doesn't work.

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba8jjt2f/) to create 3 cookies with different expiration dates: in 5 minutes, in one hour and in two hours:

```
function setCookie(cname,exSecondes) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exSecondes*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    console.log(cname + ' => ' + expires);
    document.cookie = cname + "=test;" + expires + ";path=/";
}

console.log('now in France => ' + new Date().toString());
console.log('now in France (UTC) => ' + new Date().toUTCString());

var in5Minutes = 60*5;
setCookie("in5Minutes", in5Minutes);

var inOneHour = 60 * 60 ;
setCookie("inOneHour", inOneHour);

var inTwoHours = inOneHour *2;
setCookie("inTwoHours", inTwoHours);
```

Here is the results in console:

[image]

But when debbugging with chrome dev tool, I can only see one cookie created. Why?

Thank you for any help!

**EDIT:** The cookies are well created on and IE Firefox but not on Chrome

**EDIT2:** I am on window 10 and here is my timezone:

[image]

**EDIT3:** Two others of my teammates here tried my fiddle: one got 0 cookies created, the other one got the 3 of them well created. Same version of google chrome on each compute.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and your fiddle is working correctly for me. All 3 cookies were created as intended. What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Same here too, all 3 got created

Comment: is it a coincidence that your local timezone is GMT+0100 ... and only the +2 hours cookie gets created?

Comment: I think it could come from that but I dont know why

Comment: @Victor Martins: Chrome version is 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. The two of us here that had this problem were also the two of us that played with our computer local time for testing purpose some time ago...

I restarted my computer and all works fine now. I guess that windows, when logging in, reload the Active Directory local server date/time

Hope that could help others :)

Thank everyone for helping.